# In QGIS my expression aggregation in attribute forms slow works

Tags: qgis, performance, aggregation

There are two layers: Parcels and Parking.

Parking has attribute: `parcels_objects`, this is lists of parcels intersect of parking.
When I create a parking object, I want to calculate all parcels containing parking lots and write a list of their numbers to the `parcels_objects` parking field attribute.
To do this, in the attribute forms for the `parcels_objects` field, I created an aggregate expression in default value:

```sql
aggregate(
    layer:='Parcels',
    aggregate:='concatenate', 
    expression:="parcel_number", 
    concatenator:=', ', 
    filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))
)
```

This expression works, but it is very slow because (6 seconds before opening the attribute form) there are 50,000 objects in the parcel layer.

Spatial index was created in both tables:

```sql
CREATE INDEX parcels_sx ON public.parcels USING gist (geom);
CREATE INDEX parking_sx ON public.parking USING gist (geom);
```

Dividing workflows into 2 different ones will speed up the assignment of the parcels_objects attribute, for example:

1. create objects first
2. call the process of assigning parcel numbers

But the idea is that the business process of entering information was continuous, for example:

1. the graphic object is created
2. all the attribute data for the current object are filled in (some attributes are filled in automatically) with the possibility of correction.

The virtual field in my case is not entirely suitable, since I want to calculate the parcels_objects with each edit.

Form opening slowdown occurs when the option is checked: **Apply default value on update**:
[image: aggregate in the attribute forms]
How can you make this expression run faster?

Comment: Did you consider braking up your workflow: 1. run the intersection, create an attribute based on this, 2. aggregate. To give more precise answers, however, as mentioned before, it would be helpful to see how your data looks like.

Comment: If you are trying to test things, don't use the full dataset. just use a few features until it is working. Then use the full dataset. If you only need to run the full dataset once, an hour is OK :-)

Comment: You want to update it automaticaly on every edition, do you modify it manually sometimes ? If you do not do manual modification then using a virtual field would be auto updated and may be quicker as it is not call on the form opening.